# Swapping matrix diagonals

Tags: matrices, permutations, matrix-rank

Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ matrix over a field, and consider the matrix $B$ obtained by swapping two diagonals of $A$, where the diagonals "wrap around" like in the calculation of the determinant of a $3\times 3$. For example, for $n = 3$, one valid swapping would be:

$$B = \begin{pmatrix} \color{blue}c & b & \color{red}a\\ \color{red}e & \color{blue}d & f\\ g & \color{red}i & \color{blue}h\end{pmatrix}\text{ where }A = \begin{pmatrix} \color{red}a & b & \color{blue}c\\ \color{blue}d & \color{red}e & f \\ g &\color{blue} h & \color{red}i\end{pmatrix}$$

Can this operation change the rank of a matrix?

It's easy to see that for $n = 2$ it doesn't, as it simply interchanges and transposes the set of rows and comluns of $A$. It seems that this is also the case for general $n \times n$, but I still coundn't put my finger down on a proof.

**EDIT:** One can even make the swapping cannonical if we assume it also preserves the antidiagonals. That is, given two diagonals $D$ and $D'$ inside $A$, we swap an element $a$ in $D$ with the unique element $b$ in $D'$ that lies in the same antidiagonal as $a$. The $n = 3$ example then becomes:

$$B = \begin{pmatrix} \color{blue}h & b & \color{red}e\\ \color{red}i & \color{blue}c & f \\ g & \color{red}a & \color{blue}d\end{pmatrix}\text{ where }A = \begin{pmatrix} \color{red}a & b & \color{blue}c\\ \color{blue}d & \color{red}e & f \\ g &\color{blue} h & \color{red}i\end{pmatrix}$$

I'm particularly interested in just the existence of a rank preserving swap, so this canonical one has more chance of working (eg. in the $3\times 3$ case it preserves invertibleness).

Comment: In the first swap, if $a = d = g = 1$ and $b = c = e = f = h = i = 0$, then $\operatorname{rank} A = 1$ but $\operatorname{rank} B = 3$.

Comment: @TravisWillse good catch, thanks! This doesn't happen in the canonical one though, I'm suspecting it preserves the set of all $k\times k$ minors, so it in particular preserves the rank.

Comment: In the second example $B$ can be obtained from $A$ by multiplication on the left by a permutation matrix, multiplication on the right by a permutation matrix, and taking the transpose, all three of which preserve rank, so the ranks of $A, B$ really are the same.

Comment: There is an error in the edit: there is a unique element in $D'$ if and only if the size of the matrix is odd, otherwise we gets either zero or two elements in $D'$ depending on $a$.